# Ember Actions bubbling up flow

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an template "wheels", included inside "index" template using {{render}}.

A button with an action "rotateWheels" is present in the wheels template.

My basic understanding is when the action is triggered the action bubbles up from the Templates --> Controller --> Route --> to the upper hierarchy templates Controller and Route till the Application Controller and Route. The event bubbles up and end at the ApplicationRoute.

Here in my case the bubbling path is:
Wheels Controller --> Index Controller --> Index Route --> Application Route

Here is the - [Jsbin-link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sazof/1/edit)

I am not clear why the bubbling up path differs.

Comment: did you mean to ask why there is no application controller???

Comment: @CodeJack I mean my bubbling path should be, Wheels Controller --> Wheels Route --> Index Controller --> Index Route --> Application Controller --> Application Route, But this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fine to me. The Wheels Route is skipped because you didn't use a wheels route. If you access it through a route map (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zirus/1/edit) the bubbling path passes trough the Wheels Route. The other controllers are not accessed because an action will bubble through the other routes, not controllers. See the diagram on http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got the point of bubbling of actions up the path to Application.